# Is there a Delay Delivery (scheduled emails) queue in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there any place I can check to see what emails are scheduled to be delivered via the Delay Delivery (scheduled emails) function in Outlook 2016?

Comment: Outlook client doesn't have such a queue. Maybe you can check on server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure. Outlook stores all delayed emails in the Outbox folder. Each message remains in the Outbox folder for the time that you specified.